# How to print TIFF files using MSFT Office Document imaging?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, printing, tiff

OS: Vista and Windows7

I have Microsoft Office Document Imaging installed.
.tif and .tiff files association is set to " Microsoft Office Document Imaging"

When I open a TIFF file, it opens in " Microsoft Office Document Imaging". Good so far.

However, when I right-click on the TIFF file and invoke print,  I see a "Print Pictures" dialog, ("How do you want to print your pictures?")

I have some applications installed on my machine that print incoming TIFF files on the printer. They work fine on XP. However, on Vista and Windows7, I get this "Print pictures" prompt requiring an user intervention (i.e, click on Print button).

How do I get rid of this "Print Pictures" prompt?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out you can bypass the Microsoft Office Document Imaging Print Pop-ups by     using following line of code (copy & paste into into START < RUN & then press enter):

*mspview.exe "c:\file pathway\file.tif" /p*

If you have a 'group' of files to be printed (ex/ files from a folder on your computer) you can take it one step further & incorporate this 'run line' command into a looping print sequence using Autohotkey:

---

```
TifList =      
PrintFiles=c:\file pathway\ *.tif      
MSPView=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MODI\11.0\mspview.exe

Loop, %PrintFiles%   
    TifList = %TifList%%A_LoopFileLongPath%`n
    Sort, TifList  

Loop, parse, TifList, `n

  {

    if A_LoopField =  ; Ignore the blank item at the end of the list.
        break

    Run, "%MSPView%" "%A_Loopfield%" /p
          IfMsgBox, No
            break
  }

Return
```

---

Answer (score 0):

In the GUI I haven't found a way to bypass that screen, unless you write an [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) script to automatically select the print button for you.

To bypass the prompts I usually use [this](http://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=43385&d=1134069236) command line image printer. It's great for scheduling and repetitive tasks as well. It takes the path to an image and prints it on the default printer. You can utilize it in a batch loop or however you prefer.

Detailed information on the utility is found [in this VBForums thread](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=375461). Source code included.